# How to invoke or call . /etc/bash_completion in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I am a newbie in shell scripting but I really like it where we don't have to type some really big commands and just run a shell script using terminal.

I am working in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I want to create a script that would input any package name to be installed by the user and that too with bash completion and thus it would use the command "sudo apt-get install" included in that script and take the package name given by the user and attach it with sudo apt-get install $pkgname as if pkgname is the variable to store the package name.

Seems easy...
But the problem I am facing is how to tab complete the package name while user is giving it as input.

I installed npm before and I tried read command with -e to solve this purpose but it only shows the files or directories present in the present working directory.

So I want to INVOKE/CALL the BASH_COMPLETION IN MY SCRIPT such that I am able to TAB COMPLETE PACKAGE NAME.

PLEASE HELP ME WITH THIS PROBLEM!! Text might be long but please read it and help!!

Comment: https://www.debian-administration.org/article/317/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_2

Comment: Thank you ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ sir!! This will solve my problem!!

Answer (score 0):

Passing arguments to a shell script:
$0 is the name of the command,$1 first parameter,$2 second parameter,$3 third parameter etc.
$# total number of parameters
$@ all the parameters will be listed

Visit following link for more info:
1) http://osr600doc.sco.com/en/SHL_automate/_Passing_to_shell_script.html
2) http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-to-pass-command-line-parameter-to-shell-script-254396/